# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap close Modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to close the modal that was presented to me through the open(content) function as shown in the example in the [Documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) of ng-boostrap. In the website, it mentioned that i can call close or dismiss from NgbActiveModal.

So I included NgbActiveModal in the component and tried to call dismiss() or close(). Both of them doesn't work. First of all, dismiss() is undefined (Am I importing NgbActiveModal wrong?) When I call close(), it seems to want to call some weird function inside lib.dom.d.ts which is not what I want at all. So to me it seems like I have no access to the close and dismiss provided by  ng-bootstrap even after I imported NgbActiveModal. Note that I can show the modal fine

In the example, the modal was closed via (click)="c('Close click')". I have no idea where that comes from.

So... How can I call the close() or dismiss() (Whichever works) to get rid of the modal

[image: modal dismiss]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Answer can be found here. ng-bootstrap website is missing lots of information unfortunately [Cannot close ng-bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435950/cannot-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)

Inside the component class

```
  private modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  // Modal
  open(content) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
    this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  onSave() {
    this.modalRef.close();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Even after visiting that, it is still not clear how to close() or dismiss() to get rid of the modal. I would appreciate it if you could please share how you solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with solution.

Comment: How would you do this if `content` was an `entryComponent`?

Comment: @user172902 You should mark this as the correct / accepted answer, as this is the correct way to do this and it's very difficult information to filter out from the noise.

Comment: @teddybear you can use the value returned from `this.modalService.open(content)` (which is a modalRef) as in the answer. 

Another option is to pass the modalRef to the entryComponent.

Answer (score 4):

1. At your modal component you need to add the line :

   ```
   @ViewChild('exampleModal') public exampleModal:ModalDirective;
   ```
2. At html modal you need to insert in the div root :

   ```
   #exampleModal="bs-modal"
   ```
3. At your modal component :

   ```
   onSave(){
      this.exampleModal.hide();
   }
   ```

Comment: Also import the ModelDirective in the component as import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Answer (score 0):

I followed the doc from **ng-bootstrap** with **Angular 6**. Finally I found the solution changing one line from the [original example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples):

**modal-options.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="d('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I changed from this **let-modal** to this **let-d="dismiss"** and also this 2 lines:

- (click)="d('Cross click')"
- (click)="d('Close click')"

**modal-options.ts**

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

openLg(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' });
}
```