# Angular2 ng-bootstrap Modal close in component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I will close a bootstrap modal in my component via save when input is ok.
I'm using angular v2.4.1 and [ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.19](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937699/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-close-modal) solution but I get following error:

> No provider for ViewContainerRef

I tried to add ViewContainerRef to my module.ts but I get following error:

> Type 'typeof ViewContainerRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Here the code in my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: '[add-name]',
    templateUrl: '../add-name.html'
})

export class MyComponent {   
   public errorMessage: string = '';

   constructor(public modalActive: NgbActiveModal) {}

   public saveNewStuff(name: string) {
        this.errorMessage = '';

        if (name === '' || name === undefined) {
            this.errorMessage = 'some message';
        } else if (this.errorMessage === '') {
            this.modalActive.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use [NgbModalRef](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-ref.ts) like

```
  constructor(public modalRef: NgbModalRef) {}

 public closeModal() {
    this.modalRef.close();
    this.modalRef.dismiss();
}
```

But this is not working at all. I not even getting an error message.

Comment: did you add NgbModule in your ngModule?

Comment: yeah I add "NgbModule.forRoot()" in imports of @NgModule()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to save the reference to the openend modal window to close it later like:

```
public mr: NgbModalRef;
...
public openModal(content: string) {
    this.mr = this.modalService.open(content);
}
...
public closeModal() {
   this.mr.close();
}
```

Comment: thats it! Thank you soooooo much :3

Comment: This still works lovely. Don't forget to `import { NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

Answer (score -3):

Using bootstrap modal Popup in angular 2 :

In Html : Just copy and paste bootstrap modal popup code.

In Ts File :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mymodal',
    templateUrl: 'html page url'
})
export class ModalComp {
}
```

Then you can use this component in any html view by importing in TS file.

```
import {ModalComp} from '/your component location';
```

In View :

```
<mymodal></mymodal>
```

Comment: I have no problems with the template or opening the modal

Comment: The question states angular 2