# ng-bootstrap modal not closing on cross click

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

i'm using the ng-bootstrap modal popup, and it's not closing on click of the cross button.

This is the `<a>` tag that triggers the popup -

```
<div class="actions padding-zero">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="openFilter()" class="icon configure-columns-icon">
        <span class="control-label">Configure Columns</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Modal -

```
<ng-template #filterForm let-modal>
    <div class="TitlePanel">
    Configure Columns                       
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    X
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Body
    </div>                   
</ng-template>
```

component.ts file -

```
export class NgbdModalContent {
    @Input() name;
    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-modals',
    templateUrl: './modals.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modals.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class ModalsComponent {

    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

    // Open default modal
    open(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        });
    }

    // This function is used in open
    private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
        if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
            return 'by pressing ESC';
        } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
            return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
        } else {
            return `with: ${reason}`;
        }
    }

    // Open modal with dark section
    openModal(customContent) {
        this.modalService.open(customContent, { windowClass: 'dark-modal' });
    }

    // Open content with dark section
    openContent() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    }
}
```

Also, I'm getting this error in the console when i click the close button - "Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined"

[image]

Comment: Your template references an `openFilter` method, but this isn't shown in your code.

Comment: Can you create Stack blitz demo... so we can help you

Comment: What is the version of ng-bootstrap that you are using? The `let-modal` syntax only works from 3.2.0.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource - v3.2.0.

Comment: Hi @SagarRaj Did you tried to add this `(click)="activeModal.close('Close click')"`

Comment: @core114 - Tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: can you please put your code using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: [try this, it works and you can also resolve to the result promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937699/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-close-modal)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some research and making these changes, it worked.

```
<ng-template #filterForm let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="TitlePanel">
        Configure Columns                       
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        X
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       Body
    </div>                   
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"
```

needs to be changed to

```
(click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')"
```

because you are giving

```
public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
```

Comment: Still no luck. I'm getting the same "Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined" error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `modal` but you are injecting `activeModal`. Update the html code to this:

```
<ng-template #filterForm let-modal>
    <div class="TitlePanel">
    Configure Columns                       
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    X
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Body
    </div>                   
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it's more clear now. You should use the same variable name. So change "modal.dismiss" to "activeModal.dismiss"

Comment: Still no luck. I'm getting the same "Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined" error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
[solution by   using modal reference][1]
```

[1]: [Angular 2 ng-bootstrap close Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937699/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-close-modal) **It works**