# How to close modal after form submit event in Angular2?

Tags: html, typescript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angular2-forms

I want to close modal after form submit event is finished. I've done following things:

```html
<form [formGroup]="alertForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(alertForm.value, alertForm.valid)">
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-group input-field">
          <label for="recipientLogin">Available Recipient</label>
          <textarea class="form-control validate" id="recipientLogin" required formControlName="recipientLogin"> </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-group input-field">
          <select class="form-control" id="alert_level" formControlName="alert_level">
            <option  value="0" selected> Emergency </option>
            <option value="1">Major</option>
            <option value="2">Minor</option>
            <option value="3">Information</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-group input-field">
          <label for="subject">Subject</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control validate" id="subject" required formControlName="subject">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-group input-field">
          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control validate" id="message" required formControlName="message"> </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-group input-field">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="media1" />
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="media2" />
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="media3" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="col s6">
        <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default input-field">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6 right-align">
        <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
          <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default input-field">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This triggers save() on form submit but does not close the modal for that I tried data-dismiss="modal" on save button, which block the save() call and close the modal.
I want to complete save() first after that close modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close a modal in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354041/how-can-i-close-a-modal-in-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 ng-bootstrap close Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937699/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-close-modal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot close ng-bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435950/cannot-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form is inside a *bootstrap modal*, you can use 
`$('#modalID').modal("hide")` to close the modal.

For full reference check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp).

Comment: I tried this as well, but as I'm using angular2, it's not recognizes $ command.

Comment: the idea is same but you need refer modal in angular way.
in your template refer your modal use template reference as -  #modal
and in your component add -
@ViewChild('modal') modal : ElementRef;
and then after save success add - this.modal.hide();

Comment: if you can add plunkr link it will be easier for us to help u

Comment: I tried modal.hide(), it closes my both modal and I cannot access my webpage after that(I want to close second modal open thru first modal). In seconds modal's body i'm rendering form compoent which i've created. So modal is opened from another component and want to close this from different component.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, on success of your save call you can close the modal via the 'Close' button.

`<button #btnId type="submit" />`

Which your component can close via this.btnId.click()

Comment: I want two tasks on onClick of send button:1) call to save() 2) close modal